# Why doesn't the t distribution depend on variance of the original normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, variance, standardization, t-distribution

I just find it counter intuitive that, for an arbitrary normal distribution with 0 mean and unknown variance, the t statistic of $\frac{\bar{X}}{\hat{se}} $ is completely independent of the variance of the original normal. I get that scaling by se has the effects of cancelling out the effects of the variance, but a more detailed explanation will be great. I tried to follow the derivation of t distribution online, but it's pretty hard to follow.

Comment: Look at what that "se" term is an estimate of. Do you notice anything related to the original variable's standard deviation in there?

Comment: Both $\bar X$ and $\hat{se}$ are scale random variables, with the same scale $\sigma$.

Comment: @Glen_b yeah I did say I notice that, but it doesn't completely make sense. there is no prior on $\sigma$, and to say you can capture all the information for any $\sigma$ by just approximating it using $\hat{se}$, and be completely agnostic to it, seems too good to be true.

Comment: If you have normal distribution for $X$ (which is how you get that t-statistic to have a t-distribution under the null) then estimating $\sigma$ by $s$ really does use all the information in the data about it.